# Output of Tensorflow LSTM-Cell

Tags: python, tensorflow, output, lstm

I've got a question on Tensorflow LSTM-Implementation. There are currently several implementations in TF, but I use:

```py
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_units)
```

- where n_units is the amount of 'parallel' LSTM-Cells.

Then to get my output I call:

```py
 rnn_outputs, rnn_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, x,
                        initial_state=initial_state, time_major=False)
```

- where (as `time_major=False`) `x` is of shape `(batch_size, time_steps, input_length)`
- where `batch_size` is my batch_size
- where `time_steps` is the amount of timesteps my RNN will go through
- where `input_length` is the length of one of my input vectors (vector fed into the network on one specific timestep on one specific batch)

I expect rnn_outputs to be of shape `(batch_size, time_steps, n_units, input_length)` as I have not specified another output size.
Documentation of [`nn.dynamic_rnn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn) tells me that output is of shape `(batch_size, input_length, cell.output_size)`.
The documentation of [`tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/BasicLSTMCell) does have a property `output_size`, which is defaulted to n_units (the amount of LSTM-cells I use).

So does each LSTM-Cell only output a scalar for every given timestep? I would expect it to output a vector of the length of the input vector. This seems not to be the case from how I understand it right now, so I am confused. Can you tell me whether that's the case or how I could change it to output a vector of size of the input vector per single lstm-cell maybe?

Comment: How did you get to the conclusion that each LSTM cell only outputs a scalar for every given timestep?

Comment: can you post a gist or bigger code snippet so we can see/run the code ourselves to better understand the context?

Answer (score 6):

I think the primary confusion is on the terminology of the LSTM cell's argument: `num_units`. Unfortunately it doesn't mean, as the name suggests, "the no. of LSTM cells" that should be equal to your time-steps. They actually correspond to the number of dimensions in the hidden state (cell state + hidden state vector). 
The call to `dynamic_rnn()` returns a tensor of shape: `[batch_size, time_steps, output_size]` where,

(Please note this) output_size = num_units; if (num_proj = None) in the lstm cell 
where as, output_size = num_proj; if it is defined.

Now, typically, you will extract the last time_step's result and project it to the size of output dimensions using a `mat-mul + biases` operation manually, or use the num_proj argument in the LSTM cell. 
 
I have been through the same confusion and had to look really deep to get it cleared. Hope this answer clears some of it.